# Tensorflow tf.metrics.accuracy multi-label always zero

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

My label looks like this:

```
label = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

In other words, classes 1, 4, 5 are present at the corresponding sample. I believe this is called a *soft class*.

I'm calculating my loss with:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(encoding, 7, activation=None)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=labels,
    logits=logits
)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
```

According to Tensorboard, the loss is decreasing over time, as expected. However, the accuracy is flat at zero:

```
eval_metric_ops = {
    'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=logits),
}
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', eval_metric_ops['accuracy'][1])
```

How do I calculate the accuracy of my model when using soft classes?

Comment: Is that a single label which might belong to a number of classes?

Comment: I think you are using one-hot encoding for your labels. Since this is a multi-class problem I would suggest to use the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits instead of the sigmoid. Moreover, try to apply the softmax function on the logits and feed the output as the predictions to the accuarcy instead of the logits

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this? I think the comment about softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is incorrect because you have a multi-label, (each label is a) binary-class problem.

Partial solution:

```
labels = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])  # example
predicitons = tf.constant([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])  # example
is_equal = tf.equal(label, predicitons)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_equal, tf.float32))
```

This gives a number but still need to convert it into a tf metric.